# Osmand: Map font size

Tags: osmand

I am visually impaired and have a hard time reading small fonts. In Osmand I can read the fonts when I zoom and the screen still has to be re-drawn. How can I change the default font size for street names to, say, 150%?

Answer (score 0):

In OsmAnd+ 2.3.5:

```
tap the menu button -> Configure Map -> swipe up to reveal more options
```

and set the text size from there:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Long-Press the ZoomIn button and choose a map zoom level.

Comment: Long-press zoomin button does nothing in version 1.5-arm.

Comment: It seems this "map magnifier" feature was added in v1.6, which was released quite a while ago. http://osmand.net/en/blog/90-osmand-16-release.html